# PHP - How to get ajax loaded content in file_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using `file_get_contents` function which returns all html data of page.

In that page, I am using ajax jquery requests which renders data in one of the div but I cannot get that data when I am using file_get_contents function.

Can anybody suggest the way to achieve this?

Comment: codes, we love codes not text...

Answer (score 0):

Use the AJAX request url in `file_get_contents` or in a `curl` request

Comment: I am getting data from third party providers and then I am using processing it in jquery on same page and then render output in a div.